# Determine congruency of JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a function that will search an array objects and will check if all of the objects in the array have the same property names.  I've worked up the following solution, but I'm wondering if there's any potential pitfalls with my method or an easier way to do it.

```
var objects = [{
                name: 'jon',
                department: 'HR',
                experience: 1
            }, {
                name: 'meg',
                department: 'billing',
                experience: 2
            }, {
                name: 'tom',
                department: 'accounts',
                experience: 3
            }];


            function isArrayCongruent(array) {
                //array to check congruency
                var objArray = [];
                //return bool for congruency or no
                var flag = false;
                //create array of property names
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    var o = [];
                    for (var props in array[i]) {
                        o.push(props);
                    }
                    objArray.push(o);
                }
                //get the count of properties from the first element
                var propCount = objArray[0].length;
                var propList = objArray[0] + '';
                //start comparing elements at second array element
                for (var j = 1; j < objArray.length; j++) {
                    if (propCount === objArray[j].length) {
                        //turn list of properties in into a string for ease of comparison
                        if (propList === objArray[j] + '') {
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                return flag;
            };
            console.log(isArrayCongruent(objects));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to keep an array of object's properties, use `.hasOwnProperty()` and `.getOwnPropertyNames()` instead:

```
function isArrayCongruent(array) {
    var pattern = array[0];
    var patternPropertiesCount = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(pattern).length;
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        var current = array[i];
        if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(current).length !== patternPropertiesCount) {
            return false;
        }
        for (var prop in current) {
            if (!pattern.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4x2dz/)

Comment: How far back does support go browser wise for getOwnPropertyNames?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) IE9+